# Copiar un fichero con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buenas!

Tengo un problema y **no consigo** realizar algo tan sencillo como **copiar un fichero de un lugar origen a un destino**, todo de forma local usando `Javascript`.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? He encontrado ejemplo como:

```
myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = myObject.file.copy("c:\\test.txt", "c:\\mytest.txt");
```

Pero necesito que funcione en `Chrome`.... ¿Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Te muestra algún error?, has probado en alguna carpeta, no sea que tengas problemas con los permisos?

Comment: No he conseguido nada, ni error ni nada... no se que juego de instrucciones puedo usar. 

Documentandome, encontré  WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") pero Chrome me dice que no encuentra WScript. Me da el mismo error usando ActiveXObject, pero este ultimo supongo que ActiveXObject solo funcionará en IE...

Comment: ActiveX es una tecnología de Microsoft que agrega funcionalidades a los programas de Windows. __No tiene nada que ver con jQuery__. Fuente: [https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/activex](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/activex).

Comment: Por la etiqueta HTML5, parece que quieres hacerlo a través de una página web. Me sorprendería que se pudiera hacer con Javascript "a secas", ya que sería un agujero de seguridad clamoroso (¿quieres permitir que cualquier página que visites pueda hacer los cambios que quiera? ¿A que no parece buena idea?) Antiguamente un applet firmado hubiera funcionado, pero Chrome ya no soporta Java; quizás desarrollando alguna extensión del navegador...

Answer (score 2):

**No se puede**. Los navegadores web (modernos) no dejan al javascript dentro de una página web manipular el sistema de ficheros del ordenador.

Se pueden usar plugins y extensiones y activeX y demás zarandajas, pero no hay una manera fiable que funcione en todos los navegadores mayoritarios de hoy en día.

(Nótese que sí es posible copiar ficheros usando *javascript* pero *fuera de un navegador web*, usando el módulo de sistema de ficheros de [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), véase por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js))

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionas "Chrome" te refieres a realizarlo en un navegador, eso no es posible, en un navegador solo puedes manipular dentro del navegador, no puedes manipular fuera de el, al menos usando solo ese medio. Esto es por seguridad, IE tiene el activeX en sus navegadores, que hacen que sea posible darle esa funcionalidad, Es la única forma de hacerlo directamente.

Yo queria hacer algo similar, pero lo que tuve que hacer es crear una aplicación de escritorio que manipule el escritorio, e incrustarle un servidor web local, y mi aplicacion desde la web, se conecta al servidor local y hace la manipulación. Es la única forma, delegando la función a otro proyecto de escritorio que si pueda manipularlo.

Saludos